# Immutable function as expression in CHECK constraint

Tags: postgresql

When I try to use an immutable function in the expression of a CHECK constraint I am denied at DDL-time with:

> cross-database references are not implemented

I would have thought and hoped that since I can use postgresql's boolean-returning functions in CHECK constraint expressions that I would also be able to use my own user-defined (immutable) functions as well. Here is my function I would like to call within the check constraint expression:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.isvalidtag ( Ptag text )
RETURNS bool AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( -- has illegal chars
        SELECT true from (
            SELECT unnest(regexp_matches(Ptag , '[^\w]+')) AS test
        ) nonword WHERE nonword.test != '-'
    ) THEN RETURN false;
    END IF;
    IF EXISTS ( -- has leading or trailing dashes
        SELECT true FROM (
            SELECT unnest(regexp_matches(Ptag , '(^-|-$)')) AS test
        ) misplaced WHERE misplaced.test = '-'
    ) THEN RETURN false;
    ELSE RETURN true;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Here is the table and column check that calls the function above:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tags (
    LIKE public.auditable INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS
);
ALTER TABLE public.tags ADD COLUMN tag text PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE public.tags ADD COLUMN description text;
ALTER TABLE public.tags ADD CONSTRAINT check_key_isvalidtag CHECK ( public.isvalidtag(tag) );
```

The error message reports:

> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "public.tags.tag"

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete code of your function and the check constraint you are trying to create. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The error message indicates an incorrectly written column reference, it has nothing to do with immutable functions.

Comment: Which statement causes the error?

Comment: I've conflated another error with the constraint, my apologies. How do I remove this question which may only serve to confuse?

Comment: i fail to see the logic in your requirements (and: EXISTS already yields a boolean). BTW;I would create a `domain` based on a text type with the constraint imposed on it.

Comment: can we have some more votes to close this question please?